# Deriving a recursive formula for dynamic programming

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

I'm currently trying to solve a homework problem, and I'm sort of stumped.

The problem is to pick elements from an integer array to add together to obtain the maximum sum, but 3 consecutive elements can't be picked together.

S(i) is the largest possible sum, and each element in the array is denoted by A[0...i].

First I need to come up with a recursive formula for S(i) including base cases.

I came up with base cases, but honestly I'm not sure if they're even remotely correct:

```
S(0) = max(0, A[0])
S(1) = max(S(0), A[1], A[0]+A[1])
S(2) = max(S1, A[0]+A[2], A[1]+A[2])
```

My recursive formula would then be :

```
max(0, S(i-1), S(i-2) + A[i], S(i-3) + A[i] + A[i-1])
```

Am I on the right track at least?

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: If the input has integers (which by definition can be negative), then 0 is wrong.

Comment: @trincot I believe if all the integers are negative, then it's ok to not choose any integer in which case the sum would be 0

Comment: @AntoninGAVREL Not yet, at the moment I'm just trying to grasp the basics of how to structure a solution to a dynamic programming problem.

Answer (score 1):

The maximum sum of the elements 0..i (for i>2) must be covered by exactly one of these three cases:

- doesn't include A(i)
- includes A(i) but not A(i-1)
- includes A(i) and A(i-1), but not A(i-2).

Thus, S(i) = max(S(i-1), A(i)+S(i-2), A(i)+A(i-1)+S(i-3))

The base cases can be dealt with by defining A(k)=S(k)=0 for all k<0 and reusing the same relation.

Comment: In other words, @Mike729 is on the right track :)